# Trying to install reactjs globally in Ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: root, chmod

Folks,
While trying to install reactjs using command

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Linux doesn't give write access to the specific directory.
Is there any way around it?
Or do I have to manually install packages?

Answer (score 1):

1. open your terminal
2. all you need to is just add

> sudo npm install -g create-react-app

after that, you can cd into the folder you want to create your project and run the command

> create-react-app my-app

All done.

Answer (score 0):

You are having permissions trouble while trying to install packages in node_modules folder. Try changing the permission to the folder like:

```
sudo chown -R USERNAME /PATH/TO/FILE
```

node_modules is usually located in "usr" folder in root directory under "lib". Hence you can substitute "/PATH/TO/FILE" with "/usr/lib/node_modules" and obviously "USERNAME" with you username while running the above command. Remember that you will be prompted for password to run this command. Once this is done you can try running you npm command again.

Let me know how it goes...